# Distance between two Riemann-integrable functions

Tags: riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have $RI[a,b]$ as the set of all Riemann Integrable functions and $d_1(h_\alpha, h_\beta)$ where
$$h_\alpha(t)= \begin{cases}
\alpha  & t\in\{a,b\} \\
 0 & a<t<b
\end{cases}$$

Through sketches I can see that calculated $d_1(h_\alpha, h_\beta) = 0$ but I ideally want to prove this with something more written down, I thought I could prove this using Riemann sums, so I have the formula below and would want it equal to zero as shown: $$\sum_{j=1}^n f(x_j)\Delta x = 0$$

I'm struggling with translating the information I have into this format that I could use for the sum, any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What is $d_1$? This is unclear.

Comment: It is the standard distance for integrable functions. $d_1(f,g) = \int_a^b |f-g|dx$

Comment: No, because they are $0$ on $(a,b)$. They only differ on the ends of the interval

Comment: @ALakatos Right, I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the function you are integrating is positive and you want to prove the integral is $0$ through Riemann sums. I'll prove it using upper Riemann sums tend to $0$ for sufficiently fine partitions (That would prove integrability and convergence). The key here being that they only differ on the ends of the interval.

So let $\varepsilon>0$ and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$
Given that we want to prove that $$\int_a^b |h_\alpha(x)-h_\beta(x)|dx=0$$
Take the following partition $x_0=a<x_1=\frac{\varepsilon}{2|\beta-\alpha|}<\ldots<x_{n}=b-\frac{\varepsilon}{2|\beta-\alpha|}<x_{n+1}=b$. Then our upper Riemann sums ($S_\pi$) are:
$$|S_\pi| = \left|\sum_{k=0}^n \sup_{x\in[x_k,x_k+1]}|h_\alpha(x)-h_\beta(x)| \Delta x\right| = |\beta-\alpha|\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2|\beta-\alpha|} + |\beta-\alpha|\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{2|\beta-\alpha|} = \varepsilon $$
Given that we can do this for any $\varepsilon >0$, then it follows that $S_\pi\to_{|\pi|\to0} 0 $